# Python sqlparse doesn't create new line for each column properly

Tags: python, sql, parsing, format, indentation

The common package for parsing SQL in Python is `sqlparse`:

```
pip3 install --user sqlparse
```

I wish to parse a list of `create table` statements, the library creates new lines sometimes but with wrong indentation:

```
import sqlparse;

print(sqlparse.format("create table (id int,foo text, bar float)", reindent=True, keyword_case="upper"));
```

The indentation is more and more for every subsequent line, this makes the SQL text look broken. How to tell `sqlparse` to indent properly? Tried `reindent_aligned=True` too but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my library [SQLGlot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot)

```
python -m sqlglot "create table x (id int,foo text, bar float)"

CREATE TABLE x (
  "id" INT,
  "foo" TEXT,
  "bar" FLOAT 
)
```